# No of entries of array in multidimensional array

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I am new to php. Please let me know how do I count number of array entry in under array `80cb936e55e5225cd2af`.

```
array
  'status' => int 1
  'msg' => string '2 out of 1 Transactions Fetched Successfully' (length=44)
  'transaction_details' => 
    array
      '80cb936e55e5225cd2af' =>
        array
          0 => 
            array
              ...
          1 => 
            array
              ...
```

Comment: So if you found an answer here, "ACCEPT" it !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming your array variable is $arr : ...

```
$count = count($arr['transaction_details']['80cb936e55e5225cd2af']);
```

(But this will only count the indexes/integers of that sub-array, not the values inside them!)

Answer (score 0):

You can use PHP's [`count()`](http://www.php.net/count) like this

```
$noOfEntries = count($array['transaction_details']['80cb936e55e5225cd2af']);
```

This will get you the number of arrays inside `80cb936e55e5225cd2af` (not the overall amount of elements).